# How come rems are not always computed with the same result

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain this behavior to me?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrRpeB

I don't understand how the computed font-size is larger for the inner `<span>` element than the outer `<code>` element...

```css
:root {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* font-size 1em = 10px on default browser settings */
}
span, code, div {  font-size: 1.6rem; }
```

```html
<code>Outer <span>inner</span> outer</code>
```

Comment: change the font-family of `code` and it will work

Comment: The font is exactly the same in my browser; both on StackOverflow and on codepen.io. Which browser do you use?

Comment: @AlexShesterov Correct, on FF its the same but on Chrome it's different

Comment: @TemaniAfif: how would that solve the problem? the font-family is "monospace" for the `code` as well as for the `span` elements

Comment: but when i change it, i have equal font-size

Answer (score 1):

REM as I'm sure you know stands for root em, and em's are based on the font-size of the parent element. Since the font size for each element in your example is a percentage, as in a percentage of the element size, the differently sized elements cause different font sizes to be produced. If your original root font-size was a set amount like pixels, the result would be elements containing the same sized font, such as the code snippet below.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px; /* font-size 1em = 10px on default browser settings */
}
span, code, div {  font-size: 1.6rem; }
```

```html
<code>Outer <span>inner</span> outer</code>
```

Comment: i know that rem stands for "root em", what i'm still confused about is different sizes are being computed. Since there can only be one root, it shouldn't make a difference whether you set the font-size of the root element to a percentage or a fixed unit. Since both `code` and `span` do have font-sizes specified in rem, i would assume their computed value is the same.